# reversing the function or effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the code below, and I can't figure out how to reverse the function. 
I want to go back to where it started. the very first image.
can anyone help?

```
<div id="pin_point">
<img src="images/pin_point.png"  style="position:absolute;"/>
<img src="images/pin_point_black.png" style="position:absolute;display:none;"/>
</div>



 $(function() {
 $("#pin_point").hover(function() {
    $("#pin_point img").fadeToggle('medium');
});
 $("#pin_point").click(function() {
    $("#pin_point img").attr('src', 'images/ex.png');
});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate the two images and then just set their `.src` and display state back to the starting state.

```
var imgs = $("#pin_point img");
imgs.eq(0).attr("src", "images/pin_point.png").show();
imgs.eq(1).attr("src", "images/pin_point_black.png").hide();
```

If you want a click to reset it, you would change your click handler to this:

```
$("#pin_point").click(function() {
    var imgs = $("#pin_point img");
    imgs.eq(0).attr("src", "images/pin_point.png").show();
    imgs.eq(1).attr("src", "images/pin_point_black.png").hide();
});
```

Comment: @KcLee - if you create a working jsFiddle for your code, I can show you to plug this in, but mostly you just put these three lines of code in whatever function you want to use to reset the state back to what is specified in the original HTML.

Comment: sorry, i don't know why it's not working. i can't get the working jsFiddle right now :( could you show me how to plug these 3lines in the code above. sorry.

Comment: @KcLee - See what I added to my answer.  If that's not what you want, then please explain when you want it to reset (on what type of event)?